# setup.py import all files as separate packages

Tags: python

I'm trying to make all `.py` files from a package as separate packages so that I can import them without the need to specify the package name in the import line.

What I mean is that I have a package

```
src/
|__package_A
|  |
|  |__ file_1.py
|  |__ file_2.py
|  |__ __init__.py
|__ ...other packages...
```

and I what I want to achieve is being able to import file_1 into file_2 as so

```py
from file_1 import function
```

My `setup.py` file is pretty basic

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

Right now, I'm only able to import the function from file_1 and 2 as

```py
from package_A.file_1 import function
```

which is not what I want to have based on my needs.

`package_A` is a submodule which also must work independently, so doing `from package_A.file_1` will raise an `ImportError` when trying to start the `package_A` as not a submodule.

Is there any option to make `setup()` meet such requirement?